# Nodemon does not restart when index.js file is changed

Tags: node.js, node-modules, nodemon

This is the portion from `package.json` :

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon --watch app index.js"
  },
```

All my code except the `index.js`, `package.json` and `node_modules` resides in a sub folder called `app`.

When I run using `npm run dev` , nodemon watches the changes in `app` folder and restarts if there's any changes. But won't restart if I make any changes in `index.js` (entry point)

My folder structure:

```
|-- app/
|-- node_modules/
|index.js      <--- nodemon not watching this file
|package.json
|package-lock.json
```

Why is it so?

---

**EDIT:**

Here's the solution (from @Pedro Filipe):

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon index.js"
  },
```

Comment: Hey! If you're importing files into `index.js`, I think you just need to do `nodemon index.js` in order to have the files that interest you watched. I suspect that when you pass the flag `--watch [folder_name]` it basically just ignores the filename you pass afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nodemon watches the `entry-point` to your project.
Which, In almost all the cases of node project is a single file which eventually imports other files and so on and so forth.

(Assuming that your `entry-point` is `index.js` i.e. you're importing your other files in there.) You can simply use the `nodemon index.js` as the script for your `dev`

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon index.js"
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're importing files into index.js, I think you just need to do `nodemon index.js` in order to have the files that interest you watched. I suspect that when you pass the flag `--watch [folder_name]` it basically just ignores the filename you pass afterwards.

Nodemon detects changes into the files and restarts it automatically.

Currently, you are saying node to run the index.js file which requires restart whenever you want to reflect your changes.

All you need to do is change the "start" command.

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon index.js"
}
```

(Previously commented this answer)

Comment: Thank you. Since I already accepted another answer, am upvoting your answer as a token of appreciation.

Answer (score 0):

Nodemon detects changes into the files and restarts it automatically.

Currently, you are saying node to run the index.js file which requires restart whenever you want to reflect your changes.

All you need to do is change the "start" command.

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon index.js"
  },
```

Comment: I have added the code thinking that you want to use nodemon for your "start" command.
I have updated the answer now.